# .Net Win Forms Inheritance BindingNavigator can't add buttons in child form

Tags: winforms, inheritance, data-binding, navigation

Here's one. VS 2012 framework 4.5 (though don't think this matters), C#. I have a base form with a BindingNavigator and a bindingsource. I changed the scope of these (and all the buttons though I think that is also irrelevant) to protected, and ensured GenerateItem is true.

I create a new form inheriting from this base form. In the inherited form, however, I am unable to add buttons to the BindingNavigator. Why's that, then? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please check out [How do I add a Control to a Container in an inherited WinForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092025/how-do-i-add-a-control-to-a-container-in-an-inherited-winform?rq=1).

Comment: Yeh that's it-bit of a pain and I'll have to rethink this. Thanks Ray. I can't seem to accept this as the answer as teh tick thing is not showing?