# Can't resize controls with mouse in Visual Studio 2008 (C#, .NET Compact)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I am developing a windows forms application for Windows Mobile 6 in Visual Studio 2008. There is a requirement to have some common controls on each form, such as Logo (PictureBox), Title (Label) and a small description (also Label). I decided to make a FormBase with those controls and inherit other forms from that base.

The problem is that for some reason, when I drop a Button or another control on that inherited form, I cannot resize it with my mouse. I can press Shift+Arrow to resize anything with my keyboard shortcuts, but the mouse does not work.

It's not very convenient neither for me nor for other developers in my team.

Any suggestions?

### Update 1

the base form:

```
public class FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(FormBase));
        this.pictureLogo = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.labelTitle = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.panelSeparator = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureLogo
        // 
        this.pictureLogo.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureLogo.Image")));
        this.pictureLogo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pictureLogo.Name = "pictureLogo";
        this.pictureLogo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 48);
        // 
        // labelTitle
        // 
        this.labelTitle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        this.labelTitle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.labelTitle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(54, 2);
        this.labelTitle.Name = "labelTitle";
        this.labelTitle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(183, 16);
        this.labelTitle.Text = "Title";
        // 
        // panelSeparator
        // 
        this.panelSeparator.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.panelSeparator.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(44)))), ((int)(((byte)(75)))));
        this.panelSeparator.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 50);
        this.panelSeparator.Name = "panelSeparator";
        this.panelSeparator.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(234, 1);
        // 
        // FormBase
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 320);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Controls.Add(this.panelSeparator);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelTitle);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureLogo);
        this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "FormBase";
        this.Text = "FormBase";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureLogo;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelTitle;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panelSeparator;
}
```

the inherited form:

```
public class FrontDoorForm : FormBase
{
    public FrontDoorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.buttonQuit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // buttonQuit
        // 
        this.buttonQuit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 54);
        this.buttonQuit.Name = "buttonQuit";
        this.buttonQuit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(115, 46);
        this.buttonQuit.TabIndex = 2;
        this.buttonQuit.Text = "Quit";
        this.buttonQuit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonQuit_Click);
        // 
        // FrontDoorForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 320);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonQuit);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
        this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.MinimizeBox = true;
        this.Name = "FrontDoorForm";
        this.Text = "FrontDoorForm";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.buttonQuit, 0);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonQuit;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing code, all I can say is it might be because your Derrived form is causing Initialze.. to not get called.

Comment: try this `SO` posting and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092025/how-do-i-add-a-control-to-a-container-in-an-inherited-winform

Comment: @Ryios `InitializeComponent` is being called in both the base and the inherited class constructors (at run time), although there is no `Initialize` method.

Comment: I repro.  Not exactly sure what causes it, let's call it a bug.  Change the base form's WindowState back to Normal for a workaround.  You can still get it Maximized in the derived form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close the question I will quote the answer from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647386/cant-resize-controls-with-mouse-in-visual-studio-2008-c-net-compact#comment40078120_25647386):

> Change the base form's WindowState back to Normal for a workaround. You can still get it Maximized in the derived form. [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)